# Oracle DB, reset live connections after change in the users grants

Tags: database, oracle, connection

When there is a maintenance window, we change the grants of our application user to read-only. After we relaunch our platform (after the maintenance) we put back the grants, but all the existing connections still hold the read only mode. Is there any way to reset my connections without relaunch my platform or lost my active sessions?

Comment: Are the privileges for the application user given via a role or directly to the application user ?

Comment: By role , basically they remove the write/update roles and after the maintenance they roll back to the full set of roles

Comment: Can you check if the roles (after they are granted) are enabled, you can do this by querying data dictionary view "DBA_ROLE_PRIVS" column "DEFAULT_ROLE"  for the application user.

Comment: It is not required to delete and recreate the roles. Simply enable and disable them

Comment: How do you get the initial switch to read-only role to work with requiring a logout/login?

Comment: basically is just and remove and assign task, roles are never deleted

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution by refreshing my pool connection without kill my connections...

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way that live connection can detect any variation in the roles definition ....

Comment: An approach that comes to mind. Leave the roles in place. Downgrade all update roles to a read-only profile when the DB is in maintenance (by revoking any DML privileges from roles). Then restore original privileges to the roles once maintenance is finished (by granting each DML privilege again). I wonder if that would be feasible and the changes effective in real time?

Comment: Hi Peter, sadly, we can't do that, we are talking about several roles with different configurations, we are trying to solve it in the applications side, the DB is like holly territory

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using connection pool and is able to detect broken connections, then simply kill on Oracle side all of your pool sessions after the change of rights.

For this you will need to be able to execute "ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION" in separate connection not allocated from this connection pool. You also need to make an SQL query to find SID,SERIAL# pairs for exact sessions of your application.

If connection pooling layer in your app is written good enough, it will detect each broken connection and open a new one, now with new rights. It's best not to use IMMEDIATE parameter to preserve data consistency for your application and avoid errors being reported. That will require some time until active transactions finish. If your application is making long transactions and you cannot wait too much for them, then you can use parameter IMMEDIATE.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' [IMMEDIATE];
```

You can find in Oracle on line documentation how to find sessions which belong to your application.

Comment: At the end of the day I solved the problem using hikari in combination with Aspects, Sadly, there is no way we can touch any configuration of the DB, the solution needs to be in the application site, thanks

Comment: Good to hear you solved it.
There's another option, you can somehow force disconnect of all pool connections in the application or restart pool but I suppose that's exactly something you did to solve it.

Comment: Using Reflection I'm evaluating all the connections in Hikari in order to decide which one live and which one die... , and with Aspects I'm intercepting all the calls to the DAO's, still pending the load testing...

Answer (score 0):

Using a Java Proxy over my JdbcTemplate in combination with reflection , I'm breaking the Hikari Components to extract the stack of connections.

Each Connection has a creationTime field, which helps me to decide if I want to kill or not the connection, basically any connection older than 5 min is candidate to die.

Java Proxy is just to catch the especic exception "ORA-01031" , is the only case when I cant to call the eviction component.